# View counter - how can I display most popular articles in last 10minutes?

Tags: python, django

I have views counter (I used django-hitcount)

**Models:**

```
class Article(Created, HitCountMixin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    body = RichTextField(null=False)

    hit_count_generic = GenericRelation(
        MODEL_HITCOUNT, object_id_field='object_pk',
        related_query_name='hit_count_generic_relation')
```

**Views:**

```
class AllArticlesListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'news/articles_list.html'
    model = Article
    paginate_by = 5
```

and I sort articles by number of all article views like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.model.objects.all().order_by('-hit_count_generic__hits')
```

and everything is OK.

Now **I want make most viewed in last 10minutes**, like:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.model.objects.all().order_by('-hit_count_generic__hits_in_last(minutes=10)')
```

But it doestn work... still sort articles by all views not views in last 10minutes.
How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way

```
import datetime
from django.db.models import Count

def get_queryset(self):
    period = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
    return self.model.objects.filter(
        hit_count_generic__hits__created__gte=period
    ).annotate(
        counts=models.Count('hit_count_generic__hits')
    ).order_by('-counts')
```

Comment: it gives me:
Unsupported lookup 'hits_in_last(minutes=10)' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check